# Running a PHP file using cron job in CPanel but geting some error

Tags: php, mysql, email, cron, cpanel

/home/public_html/backoffice/ca/article/mail.php: line 1: ?php: No such file or directory
/home/public_html/backoffice/ca/article/mail.php: line 2: =: command not found
/home/public_html/backoffice/ca/article/mail.php: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token '('
/home/public_html/backoffice/ca/article/mail.php: line 3: `echo $today = date('Y-m-d');'

**pls help me**

Comment: first run it in browser, check if it runs or not

Comment: when i run php file directly it is running.

Comment: can you just show me cron command

Comment: * * * * *    /home/public_html/backoffice/ca/article/mail.php

Comment: what hosting company are you running it on ?

Comment: Big Rock's hosting(linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/public_html/backoffice/ca/article/mail.php
```

Comment: Thanks it is working.

Comment: Accept this answer